# Flask application factory pattern with Flask-Mail

Tags: python, flask, flask-mail

I have a simple conceptual question about the Flask application factory pattern.

I'm trying to use **Flask-Mail** across different files. My `__init__.py` file is:

```
#
# __init__.py
#
from flask import Flask
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
from flask_mail import Mail
from flask_login import LoginManager

mail = Mail()
mongo = PyMongo()
login_manager = LoginManager()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False)
    app.config.from_object('config.DevConfig')

    mail.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    mongo.init_app(app, retryWrites = False)

    with app.app_context():
        from .views import bp
        app.register_blueprint(views.bp)
    return app
```

And the other file:

```
#
# views.py
#
from flask import Blueprint
from flask import current_app as app
from flask_mail import Message

from app import mongo, mail, login_manager

bp = Blueprint('bp', __name__, template_folder='templates', static_folder='static')

@bp.route('/')
def index():
    msg = Message("Success", recipients=[ email ])
    with open('template.html', 'r') as fd:
        msg.html = fd.read()
    mail.send(msg)
```

Though I set `MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER` in my config file, I'm getting the error that there is no default sender specified when hitting the `mail.send(msg)` line in `views.py`. After checking the `mail` object, I saw that it had no config variables set.

[Per this tutorial](https://overiq.com/flask-101/application-structure-and-blueprint-in-flask/), it seemed that I'd need to manually set `current_app.config['MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER']` whenever using the `mail` object under this pattern, and would need to write an additional `with app.app_context():` block around the `mail` object such that it was instantiated with the proper config variables.

This seems like a lot of extra work, so is there another way to directly get the `mail` object that was initialized in `create_app` with all the proper config variables set?

Appreciate the help with this!

**EDIT:**

Created `extensions.py`:

```
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
from flask_mail import Mail
from flask_login import LoginManager

mail = Mail()
mongo = PyMongo()
login_manager = LoginManager()
```

And modified `__init__.py` to be:

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False)
    app.config.from_object('config.DevConfig')

    from app.extensions import mail, login_manager, mongo
    mail.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    mongo.init_app(app, retryWrites = False)

    with app.app_context():
        from .views import bp
        app.register_blueprint(views.bp)
    return app
```

And for `views.py`, I have:

```
from flask import Blueprint
from flask import current_app
from flask_mail import Message

from app.extensions import mongo, mail, login_manager

bp = Blueprint('bp', __name__, template_folder='templates', static_folder='static')

@bp.route('/')
def index():
    msg = Message("Success", recipients=[ email ])
    with open('template.html', 'r') as fd:
        msg.html = fd.read()
    mail.send(msg)
```

Answer (score 4):

It is an import problem. Please read the [official documentation about Application Factories & Extensions](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/appfactories/#factories-extensions).

**Explanations:**

1. `__init__.py` is loaded, then *mail* object is created.
2. Somewhere, *create_app* is called, then a new *app* object is created and uses the *mail* object previously created.
3. While processing the *create_app*, blueprints are imported. (Why do you need load blueprints within the *app_context* ?)
4. While blueprint is imported, it imports `from app [...], mail`. Imports are not shared among modules (in this case for sure). So `__init__.py` is executed again while being imported and created a new *mail* object that is not configured. (If you use a debugger you will see that there are 2 mail objects.)

In the end, you have 2 *mail* object: **one is configured and one is not**.

**How to handle that:**

As written in the documentation:

> It’s preferable to create your extensions and app factories so that the extension object does not initially get bound to the application.

And they give the following example:

> You should not do:
>
> ```
> def create_app(config_filename):
>     app = Flask(__name__)
>     app.config.from_pyfile(config_filename)
>
>     db = SQLAlchemy(app)
> ```
>
> But, rather, in model.py (or equivalent):
>
> ```
> db = SQLAlchemy()
> ```
>
> and in your application.py (or equivalent):
>
> ```
> def create_app(config_filename):
>    app = Flask(__name__)
>    app.config.from_pyfile(config_filename)
>
>    from yourapplication.model import db
>    db.init_app(app)
> ```

Finally, you should create your *mail* object in a different file and import it your `__init__.py`. If you only use the *mail* object in this blueprint, it could be declared directly in this blueprint.

You can find a full [example: Flaskr (Official example)](https://github.com/pallets/flask/tree/master/examples/tutorial/flaskr) that uses a DB extension as you use Flask-Mail.

***Why is it so confusing?*** Most of the examples you can find on Google, do not use application factories and are always in one file. In their case, you will declare everything in the same file. In your case, you will share objects among modules, so they should be accessible correctly.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply! I moved everything to a separate file (`extensions.py`), as specified in the edit to the original question, but am still unable to get it to import `mail` correctly. Any thoughts on the above changes?

Comment: What is the error that you get ? Adding the stacktrace could be useful.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't get any error, the email just fails to send silently. I'm starting to think this is something Flask-Mail specific since Flask-Mongo and Flask-Login are working properly with this pattern.

Comment: I helped you with the mail object, but after that, without error logs, I can not do anything more.